# cp in a bash script

Tags: macos, bash, shell

I am working on a simple shell script (my first one) and cannot seem to figure out why this is failing when I run `./auto.sh baz`. It was working initially when I had hard coded in the full destination path, but now that I want to use an argument it breaks. Any help would be awesome. Thanks!

```
#!/bin/sh

cp -ivr ./foo/bar.xcodeproj ./iOS/$1.xcodeproj
```

Comment: What is the exact error message, or how else do you determine that it breaks?  Does the target directory already exist?  What happens if you invoke `./auto.sh baz2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following

```
#!/bin/sh
cp -ivr "./foo/bar.xcodeproj" "./iOS/${1}.xcodeproj"
```

Comment: If I have other arguments following, do I need to wrap them in quotes and brackets also?

Comment: It's a good habit to do so. Also make sure you execute the script from the same directory, else you need to `cd`.